# Integer template parameters and subfunction calls

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, eigen3

In this short snippet, I want to create an Eigen::Tensor (in the unsupported module), with aribtrary dimensions.

```
template
<typename T>
Tensor<T, 2> convertNPToEigen2D(np::ndarray const & arr)
{
  //Some checking...
  T* raw_arr_data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr.get_data());
  TensorMap<Tensor<T, 2>> arr_eigen(raw_arr_data,
            arr.shape(0), arr.shape(1));
  //...
  return arr_eigen;
}
```

You can of course see that without variadic templates, I have to duplicate this function for every possible number of dimensions. This seems like a pretty basic examples, where variadic templates can avoid a lot of code duplication:

```
template
<typename T, uint64_t dims>
Tensor<T, dims> convertNPToEigenND(np::ndarray const & arr)
{
  //Some checking...
  T* raw_arr_data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr.get_data());
  TensorMap<Tensor<T, dims>> arr_eigen(raw_arr_data,
            /*arr.shape(0), ..., arr.shape(dims-1)*/);
  //...
  return arr_eigen;
}
```

I have several problems translating this into variadic template code,since I don't have an argument pack. I guess it would also be possible to let the caller do the work, i.e.

```
convertNPToEigenND<float, arr.shape(0), arr.shape(1), arr.shape(2)>(arr)
```

but I would prefer the above solution if it is possible.
I thought it would be easy to look this problem up, but most of the questions I have found deal with an existing argument pack instead of creating one.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

Thanks, the solution worked perfectly. Just another simple extension I need would be:

```
array<int, sizeof...(Is)> shuffle_tens = { Is... };
reverse(shuffle_tens.begin(), shuffle_tens.end());
```

I tried using a simple solution from [this site](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/compile-time-integer-sequences/), but it tells me "cannot convert from 'ints<5,4,3,2,1,0>' to 'int'".

Thanks again to Jarod42,

```
array<int, sizeof...(Is)> shuffle_tens = { (sizeof...(Is) - Is - 1)... };
```

works for me.

Comment: You could probably take a look at index sequences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <typename T, size_t ... Is>
Tensor<T, sizeof...(Is)> convertNPToEigenNDHelper(np::ndarray const & arr,
                                                  std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  //Some checking...
  T* raw_arr_data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr.get_data());
  TensorMap<Tensor<T, sizeof...(Is)>> arr_eigen(raw_arr_data, arr.shape(Is)...);
  //...
  return arr_eigen;
}

template
<typename T, uint64_t dims>
Tensor<T, dims> convertNPToEigenND(np::ndarray const & arr)
{
    return convertNPToEigenNDHelper<T>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<dims>());
}
```

`std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` are C++14, but can be implemented in C++11.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its simple and pretty neat! I updated the question with another smaller subquestion ;)

Comment: Isn't `(N - Is)...` do the job ?